# MongoDB: match non-empty doc in array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection structured thusly:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  score: [
    {
      foo: 'a',
      bar: 0,
      user: {user1: 0, user2: 7}
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find all documents that have at least one 'score' (element in score array) that has a certain value of 'bar' and a non-empty 'user' sub-document.

This is what I came up with (and it seemed like it should work):

```
db.col.find({score: {"$elemMatch": {bar:0, user: {"$not":{}} }}})
```

But, I get this error:

```
error: { "$err" : "$not cannot be empty", "code" : 13030 }
```

Any other way to do this?

Comment: Is that *exactly* how it's structured? Seems a bit off.

**> var doc = { score: [ foo: 'a', bar: 0, user: { user1: 0, user2: 7 } ] };  
Thu Jul  7 00:43:42 SyntaxError: missing ] after element list (shell):1**

Comment: @Justin: you're right, forgot the braces inside the array.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Figured it out: `{ 'score.user': { "$gt": {} } }` will match non-empty docs.

Comment: In this case, `score.user` is an object. Would it also work to check if `score`, an array, is empty?

Comment: It might, but for arrays you're probably better off using: `{ foo: { $not: { $size: 0 } } }`

Comment: excelent! I tested, and both worked.
Do you know why second option would be better?

Comment: @knoxxs: see the docs on sort order: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/ - an empty doc sorts before any non-empty doc, but a null will sort before any (including empty) doc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I quite understand your schema, but perhaps the most straight forward way would be to not have an "empty" value for **score.user** ?

Instead purposely **not** have that field in your document if it has no content?

Then your query could be something like ...

```
> db.test.find({ "score" : { "$elemMatch" : { bar : 0, "user" : {"$exists": true }}}})
```

i.e. looking for a value in ***score.bar*** that you want (0 in this case) checking for the mear existence ($exists, [see docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists)) of ***score.user*** (and if it has a value, then it'll exist?)

**editied**: oops I missed the $elemMatch you had ...

Comment: Yes, I've thought of doing it that way, the main reason I'd prefer a query that matches both non-existent and empty `user` is that individual user scores can be removed and I'd rather not have to check whether the subdoc is empty and needs to be removed every time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add an auxiliary array that keeps track of the users in the `user` document:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  score: [
    {
      foo: 'a',
      bar: 0,
      users: ["user1", "user2"],
      user: {user1: 0, user2: 7}
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can add new users atomically:

```
> db.test.update({_id: 1, score: { $elemMatch: {bar: 0}}},                       
... {$set: {'score.$.user.user3': 10}, $addToSet: {'score.$.users': "user3"}})
```

Remove users:

```
> db.test.update({_id: 1, score: { $elemMatch: {bar: 0}}},
... {$unset: {'score.$.user.user3': 1}, $pop: {'score.$.users': "user3"}})
```

Query scores:

```
> db.test.find({_id: 1, score: {$elemMatch: {bar: 0, users: {$not: {$size: 0}}}}})
```

If you know you'll only be adding non-existent users and removing existent users from the `user` document, you can simplify `users` to a counter instead of an array, but the above is more resilient.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the $size operator for checking array sizes.

Comment: I'm not checking the size of any arrays.  I left out a set of braces before, may be more clear now. An equivalent operator for documents/objects would work, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        tasks: {
          $addToSet: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: ['$tasks.id', ''],
                  },
                  '',
                ],
              },
              then: '$$REMOVE',
              else: {
                id: '$tasks.id',
                description: '$tasks.description',
                assignee: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: ['$tasks.assignee._id', ''],
                        },
                        '',
                      ],
                    },
                    then: undefined,
                    else: {
                      id: '$tasks.assignee._id',
                      name: '$tasks.assignee.name',
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
```