# How to query against a null sub collection of documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data:

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "FirstName" : "John",
  "LastName" : "Doe",
  "Test" : [{
      "TestId" : ObjectId("5046109daedabb0cf8800f3f"),
      "DateTaken" : ISODate("2012-09-10T15:46:32.866Z")
    }, {
      "TestId" : ObjectId("506e0928aedabb087c4ec9d1"),
      "DateTaken" : ISODate("2011-06-26T18:05:52.625Z"),
      "Responses" : [{
          "AnswerId" : "506e0928aedabb087c4ec98c",
          "QuestionId" : ObjectId("506e0928aedabb087c4ec98b"),
          "ResponseDate" : ISODate("2011-06-26T04:00:00Z")
        }]
    }]
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "FirstName" : "Jane",
  "LastName" : "Doe",
  "TestHistory" : [{
      "TestId" : ObjectId("506e0928aedabb087c4ec9d1"),
      "DateTaken" : ISODate("2011-06-26T18:05:52.625Z"),
      "Responses" : [{
          "AnswerId" : "506e0928aedabb087c4ec98c",
          "QuestionId" : ObjectId("506e0928aedabb087c4ec98b"),
          "ResponseDate" : ISODate("2011-06-26T04:00:00Z")
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am trying to write a query that returns all instances where there exist Test that has no Responses.  I have tried the following queries:

> 1. { "Test.Responses": { $exists: false } }
> 2. { $and: [ { Test: { $exits: true } }, { "Test.Responses": { $exists: false} } ] }

Both of which return 0 results.  What am I missing?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607102/mongodb-match-non-empty-doc-in-array. See the comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607102/mongodb-match-non-empty-doc-in-array#comment18700846_6838057

Comment: Note, unlike testing for the non-empty value of a field, `$size` does not use an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is this:

```
db.foo.find({
    Test: { $elemMatch: {
        Responses: { $exists: false }
    }
})
```

Otherwise, your query would look for an record where all documents under `Test` doesn't have the `Responses` property.